# Boost grace period on varnish when error 500 ocurred

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I use the following code to boost the grace period in varnish when i receive error 500 from the backend:

```
# If backend returns 500 error then boost the cache grace period...
if (beresp.status == 500) {
   set beresp.grace = 1m;
return (retry);
}
```

But i want only boost the grace period when i have another cache, if i don't have cache, i just want to cache the error.

Backend response configuration "vcl_backend_response" for the cache:

```
# Cache 1 day
if(bereq.url ~ "^/"){
    set beresp.http.X-cachePath = beresp.http.X-cachePath +  "1d::";
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    set beresp.ttl = 1d;
    set beresp.grace = 1h;
    return (deliver);
}
```

Is this possible do it with varnish 4 ?

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Saint Mode](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#grace-and-saint-mode). [Here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleSaintMode) is an example.

What Saint Mode does is similarly to Grace Mode but in a different situation, while Grace Mode acts when backend is sick or takes too long to respond, Saint Mode acts when *you* don't like the backend response.

In this case, the 500 error is the response that you don't like.

It's a pitty that Saint Mode has been removed from Varnish core in version 4. Despite not being as easy as in Varnish 3, [here](https://github.com/daghf/libvmod-saintmode) is a VMOD for Saint Mode in Varnish 4